# Intellij editor does not resolve crypto package classes?

Tags: intellij-idea

**Ver 14.1.1 Ultimate:**

[image]

Can somebody please explain what is going on, what is the so special about crypto package mysterious behavior?

A. `Mac` class is unresolved according to editor.

B. `SecretKeySpec` is resolved only via .* notation and would give the same underscore red marking error if I would import individually the class.

C. **I can run the method so it compiles?!**

Comment: try File -> Invalidate Caches / restart. Sometimes helps with this kind of issues.

Comment: @SatteliteSD Doing that atm, thx, waiting for indexes to update.

Comment: @SatelliteSD Bless you, it worked please post as an answer and I will accept it. God sake ... at the end of the day encountering stuff like this.

Comment: Fine! Happy crypting :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad I could help :)

IntelliJ has some hickups from time to time, in such cases I choose `File` -> `Invalidate caches and restart`. This is my first best shot at such kind of issues, and mostly the go away with that.